# Can I run an unpriviledged command prompt from an administrative account on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, administrator

I have a Windows 7 VM where the user is an administrator. Every time I try to run cmd it opens with administrative access (as visible on the titlebar).

Is it possible to run cmd from this account without administrative privileges?

I am launching it from the start menu.

Comment: A program will only run in elevated mode if started from a program which is already in elevated mode. Please better describe your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible from the Start-Menu, unless you create a shortcut pointing to a CLI script.

You can use the program runas.exe from a command prompt to open a second command prompt in the context of an other user.
From a command prompt:

```
runas /u:yourdomain\youruser c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

where youruser is a standard user account.